# Run two operations atomically

Tags: java, database, android-studio, concurrency

I am currently experimenting with android studio and I have run into a little problem. I have a few pieces of code where I try to do two things at once. One such example is this:

1. Delete an object from a remote database.
2. Delete the same object from the local database.

Both operations run on a thread of their own. However, I would like to ensure that I do these two operations atomically. Maybe the user looses internet connection and the app manages to delete the object from the local database but not from the remote database. I would like to ensure that that does not happen. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[1] Delete the object from the remote database first.

After that, check if it is deleted or not.

If yes, delete it from the remote database.
If not, do not delete it.

[2] Check if the device is connected to the internet before proceeding with the deletions.

I would personally prefer the first method.

Comment: I am sorry. I think there is a typo in the first line. Since you wrote remote database twice. That should work. Although I would have prefered it if I could avoid doing any more operations. This mthod requires that I do a check through the database again.